# drawing shapes with core graphics that aren't filled in (circle with just border)

Tags: iphone, core-graphics, cgcontext

HI,
i'm trying to draw a circle in my iphone app that just draws a circle with no fill. Any tips on how to do this? I was trying to use CGContextSetStrokePattern but I have no idea how to define a pattern?

Answer (score 2):

How about no pattern and using [CGContextStrokePath()](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html)?

Comment: steve: Yeah, `CGContextSetStrokePattern` is for if you want a stroke that's multi-colored in some way. If you want just a solid-color stroke, no pattern—just set the stroke color, then stroke.